# How to delete first letter of text box(for each line)

Tags: c#

I want to delete first char of all lines in the text box multiline for example

:hello:hi
Amat:az
:bye:hello

result:
hello:hi
mat:az
bye:hello
I cant use substrings PLZ help

```
textBox1.Lines = textBox1.Lines.substring("1");
```

Comment: Why you can not use substring

Comment: `Substring` works as follows. `"test".Substring(1)` returns `est`

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ. I think the question is 'I don't know how to use `Substring`'

Comment: Ya, @PeterSmith I was asking to hear the arguments, but looks like you are right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Lines property is an array of strings, you should use methods that works on array or execute a loop over that array to apply your changes.

A single line that will do you request is (with a check for empty lines)

```
 textBox1.Lines = textBox1.Lines.Select(x => x.Length > 0 ? x.Substring(1) : "").ToArray();
```

The loop approach is more complex because the array returned by the Lines property is a copy of the array stored in the Lines property. So a code like this will never work

```
// Reading from a copy and assigning to a copy, will not work
for(int x = 0; x < textBox1.Lines.Length; x++)
    textBox1.Lines[x] = textBox1.Lines[x].Substring(1);
```

Instead, you need

```
List<string> clippedLines = new List<string>();
for(int x = 0; x < textBox1.Lines.Length; x++)
    clippedLines.Add(textBox1.Lines[x].Length > 0 ?  
                     textBox1.Lines[x].Substring(1) : "");

// Replacing the whole Lines array will work   
textBox1.Lines = clippedLines.ToArray();
```

Comment: you should check for null values and empty strings

Comment: Added the check for empty lines (null should not be possible in the Lines array)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why the restriction on SubString (as mentioned in OP), but if you cannot use SubString, you could do the following.

```
 textBox1.Lines = textBox1.Lines.Select(x => string.Join(string.Empty, x.Skip(1))).ToArray();
```